# mdadm raid1, [1/2] disks failed, safe to reboot?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mdadm, raid1

I am seeing the following under /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sda2[0](F) sdb2[1]
976554876 blocks super 1.1 [2/1] [_U]
bitmap: 4/8 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0](F) sdb1[1]
204788 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

It appears /dev/sda has failed.  However, raid1 is redundant so my system should still be able to operate.  This however, is not the case, my entire file system has been kicked into Read-only mode.

```
Running mdadm --detail gives me:
sudo: Can't open /var/run/sudo/supertrader/18: Read-only file system
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.0
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 16 18:04:44 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 204788 (200.02 MiB 209.70 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 204788 (200.02 MiB 209.70 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Mar  1 09:48:13 2012
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync

       0       8        1        -      faulty spare
```

At this point, I would like to get the machine operating again (filesystem not locked in read-only mode) while I get somebody at the datacentre to replace the failed drive.

When I tried removing the failed drive using:

```
      mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda2
```

I get an error message about /dev/sda2 not found.

My question is the following:
(1)  What happens if I reboot the system now, will it automatically come up without the failed disk? Or do I need to find some way to actually remove the disk from the software array. I'm not local to the machine so if it gets stuck while booting, it is a real pain to fix.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT2:
I went ahead with the reboot and the system came up again, this time with the filesystem mounted rw

I am not sure what happened, but it looks like the 'failed' disk came back online? here is the /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      976554876 blocks super 1.1 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 5/8 pages [20KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      204788 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Prior to this, I had run:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -r --force detached
```

I did this on both md0 and md1.  md0 now looks normal, any idea what is happening with md1?

EDIT:
Also, I noticed that under /dev/ both sda and sdb are missing, in fact, I only have sdc1 and sdc2.

What is going on here, why are both of my raid disks missing?

fdisk -l output:

Disk /dev/md0: 209 MB, 209702912 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 51197 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Disk /dev/md1: 1000.0 GB, 999992193024 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 244138719 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-0: 27.9 GB, 27917287424 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3394 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/dm-1: 972.1 GB, 972071895040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 118181 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/dm-1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009984e

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdc2              26      121602   976556032   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Is there a sure way to find out which is my surviving disk hardware wise?

Comment: Is the system remote did you install the bootloader to both disks?

Comment: does executing `partprobe` make your machine recognize again `sda` and `sdb`?

Comment: I did a standard mdadm raid1 with LVM, I'm not sure if that puts the bootloaded on both disks.

Comment: also, running partprobe ends up with failed to re-read the partition table, device or resource busy.  however, i do get this message for sda, sdb, and md0

Comment: finally, i did go ahead and reboot the system and now my raid is mounted as rw again.  i edited my original post above and put the new /proc/mdstat message